"Invalid notification (no valid small icon)" error while using "flutter_local_notifications" package
I want to show a simple notification in flutter. this is my source code :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyScreen> createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin? flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  var initializationSettings;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    initializePlatformSpecifics();
  }

  initializePlatformSpecifics() {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('assets/logo128.ico');
    initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
  }

  Future<void> showNotification() async {
    var androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'CHANNEL_ID',
      'CHANNEL_NAME',
      //"CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION",
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      playSound: true,
      timeoutAfter: 5000,
      styleInformation: DefaultStyleInformation(true, true),
    );
    var platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin!.show(
      0, // Notification ID
      'Test Title', // Notification Title
      'Test Body', // Notification Body, set as null to remove the body
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'New Payload', // Notification Payload
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 239, 241, 249),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          showNotification();
        },
        child: Text(
          "Show Notification!",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

But after the click the "Show Notification!" this error occurs :

Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(error,
Invalid notification (no valid small icon):
Notification(channel=CHANNEL_ID shortcut=null contentView=null
vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000
vis=PRIVATE), null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=CHANNEL_ID
shortcut=null contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0
flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)

Please help me.
I used also these commands but problem don't resolved :
var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png');
var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
This is my vs code screenshot :
vs code screenshot

The problem is that the initialization function of FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin is not being called. Try something like this:
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin? flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  late final InitializationSettings initializationSettings;

  _initializeFlutterLocalNotifications() async {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    const initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin?.initialize(
      const InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initializeFlutterLocalNotifications();
  }

And I remember having a problem because of how I was passing the defaultIcon path, and passing as '@mipmap/ic_launcher' solved the issue.

My problem resolved. thanks @renato-willyan

@programmer1360 Glad I could help! If you don’t mind, mark the answer as accepted.

Yes, of course! (after the site allows voting)
